# How to search for class names in a html file using regex?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I was wondering myself if I want to get all classes names in a html file, what `regex` can I use? I don't understand the way I can mount it. I have this code:

HTML

```
<html>
    <div class="myFirstClass"></div>
    <div class="mySecondClass2"></div>
</html>
```

I want to know how to get:

```
myFirstClass
mySendCLass2
```

using regex... I tried to use `class=".*"` but it gets everything ever outside of the name.

Comment: rather than regex use xpath to query dom

Comment: or use a framework like jquery to ask for classes

Comment: `<script>var class="some variable";</script>`

Comment: First of all, what language are you using ? Have you considered using an HTML parser ?

Comment: [Mandatory Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *(someone had to do it and it's still amazingly fun to read)*

Comment: Adding this as a comment rather than just editing your post, but your HTML is invalid (the closing tags on the divs).

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also every regex question should contain the language/flavor being used, there are some differences in syntax and capabilites between each flavor. **To all the guys who answered** with their "favorite" language: **do not answer** because it's **useless** for the OP and even for future visitors.

Comment: @Amith Why in the  world did you change the tags to JS and jQuery ?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Please don't post links to that question, because they are not helpful to the reader, unless you follow it up with something that is an answer they can use.  *You* know the point of the comment and that wall of text is that parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea.  However, to someone else who is asking, that is not at all clear.  Worse, it doesn't point the reader to any useful solutions that *can* help parse HTML reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map function`

```
var classes= $("div").map(function() {
    return this;
}).get();
for(i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
    console.log($(classes[i]).attr('class'));
}
```

**JSFiddle link of working code**

http://jsfiddle.net/mkamithkumar/dLkkY/

Answer (score 2):

Your example of `"class=".*"` seems on-track, but the main problem with these is that the * is "greedy" - it will take as many characters as it can, probably then matching the last quotation mark in the line.

One option is to use `\w` instead of `.`, to only retrieve word characters. Depending on the language you're using, I would think an HTML parser might be a better option. Many languages have such libraries available.

NOTE: Unless your usage is pretty basic, a regex with \w would also need to account for space-seperated multiple class names.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Regex for parsing HTML. If you're using .NET, you can use something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

For your particular query, you could probably do something like;

```
var classNames = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div")
    .Select(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are eager by default, so the `".*` will get everything starting with `"` and ending with `"` for the longest string possible. What you need is for it to stop on the first matching `"`. Try this:

```
class=\"[^\"]*\"
```